# Density of integers with prime factors at most $k$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I start with a quick example: Given a large random integer $N$, we are told to round it down to the closest power of $2$ and find what fraction of $N$ must be lopped off. Clearly the answer is between $0$ and $1/2$.

Now to get to the question: Call a number $k$-smooth if its prime factors are all $\le k$. Define $f(k,N)$ as the difference between $N$ and the largest $k$-smooth number $\le N$. We'd like to understand $f(k,N)$ or at least some of its statistical properties, like the expectation which is defined by :

$$\lim_{M \to \infty} E_{N<M} [f(k,N)/N] $$

which may not exist. $f(2,N)$ was the example in the first paragraph. We would like to know:

1-      If we fix $k$, what is the behavior of the sequence $E_{N<M} [f(k,N)/N]$ or the functional form of $f(k,N)/N$ and if its limit exists, then what is it? Is it positive, or does it tend to zero? This is somewhat answered later.

2-     If $k$ is about $\log(N)$ does one know that $f(k,N)$ is typically less than some function (more on that in the last paragraph)?

We asked this question to Noam Elkies and he had some thoughts on the case of $f(3,N)$ (where $2,3$ prime factors are allowed) and question 2. I paraphrase his reply:

For $k=3$, note that since $t = \log_2(3)$ is irrational the sequence $$\{t , 2t , 3t , 4t , . . . \} \pmod 1$$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.  We find that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $M$ such that for all $N > M$ there is a $3$-smooth number between $N$ and $(1+\epsilon)N$, and thus that the relative error in replacing $N$ by the nearest $3$-smooth number approaches zero. So, $f(3,N)$, in expectation, goes to zero.

Regarding how fast the relative error decays to zero when we are allowed $r$ number of prime factors, the answer should be on the order of $\log(N)^{1-r}$ where $r$ is the number of allowed prime factors, but we don’t know whether anything like that has been proved.

Comment: This is basically the second moment of the gaps between smooth numbers.  For $k$ much larger than $\log N$ the state of the art is summarised in this paper of Heath-Brown: https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.02947

Comment: It is known that if $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \dots$ are the $3$-smooth numbers, then $n_{i+1}-n_i = O(n_i/(\log n_i)^{C})$ for a certain constant $C>0$.  See: Tijdeman, in` On the maximal distance between integers composed of small primes', Compositio Mathematica, tome 28, no 2 (1974), p. 159--162